# How to reset window grid contents on Python Tkinter when button is pushed?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a basic application, and want people to be able to follow prompts on the same window, like when installing an application and clicking next... and then finish etc...

I have a basic window with a button, but how do I clear the contents of the grid so I can repopulate it?

```
import tkinter as tk

def nextbtn():
    #clear window to start fresh
    #then change the text
    mybrain="notsure"


root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(background='#e3e5e8')

root.title("Test Utility")
root.geometry("500x400")
tk.Label(root, text=
         """This is my test application. Press Next to continue.

            """.format(localIp), background='#e3e5e8').grid(row=0, column=2,columnspan = 2)
tk.Button(text='Next',command=nextbtn, background='#e3e5e8').grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=tk.W, pady=4)

root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
w = 500 # width for the Tk root
h = 400 # height for the Tk root

# get screen width and height
ws = root.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
hs = root.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen

# calculate x and y coordinates for the Tk root window
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)

# set the dimensions of the screen 
# and where it is placed
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

root.mainloop() # starts the mainloop
```

what I would like to do is when button is pushed clear grid, and then replace the text "this is my test app..." with "hello world!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to clear the whole grid to update a label.

You should save a reference to your label and update it's `text` attribute when the button is pressed.

```
def nextbtn():
    my_label['text'] = "Hello World"

my_label = tk.Label(root, text="This is my test application. Press Next to continue.")
```

If you will be making significant changes in each phase of your application, then you should use a `frame` to hold your `widgets` and `.destroy()` it after each phase.